# Change Mesa driver in Ubuntu 18.04 VM under VMware Workstation 15 Player

Tags: drivers, vmware, opengl

I'm running a Ubuntu 18.04 VM under VMware Workstation 15 Player.

One application that I'd like to run crashes because it comes with its own LLVM shared libraries which interfer with the system's ones, in particular with the LLVM libraries used by the Mesa OpenGL driver.

Here's the relevant output of `glxinfo`:

```
$ glxinfo
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    [snip]
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    [snip]
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    [snip]
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: VMware, Inc. (0x15ad)
    Device: SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;  LLVM; (0x405)
    Version: 19.0.8
    Accelerated: no
    Video memory: 1MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 3.3
    Max compat profile version: 3.3
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 2.0
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;  LLVM;
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.0.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
```

**Is there a way to instruct Mesa to use a different backend that doesn't rely in any way on LLVM? I'm fine with severely degraded rendering performance.**

As far as my attempts go, based on https://www.mesa3d.org/envvars.html, I've tried setting `GALLIUM_DRIVER` to `softpipe` or `swr` but it didn't seem to have any effect, the application would still crash.

Here's the relevant part of the callstack when the application crashes:

```
#0  0x00007fffe32cff5b in llvm::RegisterPassParser<llvm::MachineSchedRegistry>::NotifyAdd(llvm::StringRef, void* (*)(), llvm::StringRef) ()
   from /home/franz/Projects/prebuilt-linux-deps/lib/libLLVMCodeGen.so.5
#1  0x00007fffc88cb43d in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-7.so.1
#2  0x00007ffff7de5733 in call_init (env=0x555555eef760, argv=0x7fffffffde08, argc=1, l=<optimized out>) at dl-init.c:72
#3  _dl_init (main_map=main_map@entry=0x555556009f40, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffde08, env=0x555555eef760) at dl-init.c:119
#4  0x00007ffff7dea1ff in dl_open_worker (a=a@entry=0x7fffffffc7b0) at dl-open.c:522
#5  0x00007ffff32c22df in __GI__dl_catch_exception (exception=0x7fffffffc790, operate=0x7ffff7de9dc0 <dl_open_worker>, args=0x7fffffffc7b0) at dl-error-skeleton.c:196
#6  0x00007ffff7de97ca in _dl_open (file=0x7fffffffca40 "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so", mode=-2147483390, caller_dlopen=0x7fffd966dfca, nsid=<optimized out>, argc=1, argv=<optimized out>, 
    env=0x555555eef760) at dl-open.c:605
#7  0x00007ffff1dd6f96 in dlopen_doit (a=a@entry=0x7fffffffc9e0) at dlopen.c:66
#8  0x00007ffff32c22df in __GI__dl_catch_exception (exception=exception@entry=0x7fffffffc980, operate=0x7ffff1dd6f40 <dlopen_doit>, args=0x7fffffffc9e0) at dl-error-skeleton.c:196
#9  0x00007ffff32c236f in __GI__dl_catch_error (objname=0x555555ba6270, errstring=0x555555ba6278, mallocedp=0x555555ba6268, operate=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>) at dl-error-skeleton.c:215
#10 0x00007ffff1dd7735 in _dlerror_run (operate=operate@entry=0x7ffff1dd6f40 <dlopen_doit>, args=args@entry=0x7fffffffc9e0) at dlerror.c:162
#11 0x00007ffff1dd7051 in __dlopen (file=<optimized out>, mode=<optimized out>) at dlopen.c:87
#12 0x00007fffd966dfca in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0
#13 0x00007fffd967109e in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0
#14 0x00007fffd9648e34 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0
#15 0x00007fffd9644af2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0
#16 0x00007fffd9645e42 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0
#17 0x00007ffff179d651 in glXChooseFBConfig () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0
#18 0x00007ffff7feb30f in ?? () from /home/franz/anaconda3/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so
#19 0x00007ffff7feb505 in ?? () from /home/franz/anaconda3/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so
#20 0x00007ffff7fe88d1 in ?? () from /home/franz/anaconda3/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so
#21 0x00007fffdc59a4ea in QXcbWindow::create() () from /home/franz/anaconda3/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#22 0x00007fffdc58caec in QXcbIntegration::createPlatformWindow(QWindow*) const () from /home/franz/anaconda3/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#23 0x00007ffff3dfb62d in QWindowPrivate::create(bool, unsigned long long) () from /home/franz/anaconda3/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
```

As one can see, `libGLX_mesa.so.0` ends up calling into `/home/franz/Projects/prebuilt-linux-deps/lib/libLLVMCodeGen.so.5` (which is the app's LLVM shared libs) and crashing.

Comment: Did you find a solution or the reason why it crashed? I'm running into a similar issue, the rasterizer it is trying to load is swrast_dri.so and then it throws an exception (i.e. I also see llvm::PassRegistry methods in the stacktrace. In my case the only difference with loaded so's compared to glxgears is my use of libGLEWmx1.13 instead of libGLEW (because I want to support multiple contexts and muiltiple views)

Comment: @StarShine Sadly, I didn't. I'm still very interested in finding a solution though.